# Removing unicode symbols from column names

Tags: r

I am trying to grab some statistics from the fifa.com by using XML package. The import is successful but the column names have unicode symbols. I want to remove those symbols.

This is how I have got the data,

```
library(XML)
url <- "http://www.fifa.com/worldcup/statistics/teams/disciplinary.html"
foulbycountry <- readHTMLTable(url)
foulbycountry1 <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, foulbycountry)
```

The variable names include two characters that I want to remove. I have tried to create a new object but it is not working. For example,

```
country <- foulbycountry1$Teams▴▾
fouls.committed <- foulbycountry1$Fouls Committed▴▾
```

which gives me the following output,

```
> country <- foulbycountry1$Teams▴▾
Error: unexpected input in "country <- foulbycountry1$Teams�"
> fouls.committed <- foulbycountry1$Fouls Committed▴▾
Error: unexpected symbol in "fouls.committed <- foulbycountry1$Fouls Committed"
```

Is there any way you can suggest so that I can remove those extra unicode characters?

Comment: An alternative to removing the characters would be to use backticks around the column names....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iconv` is one option ...

```
names(foulbycountry1) <- iconv(names(foulbycountry1), to='ASCII', sub='')
names(foulbycountry1)
# [1] "Teams"                           "Teams"                           "Matches Played"                 
# [4] "Yellow Card"                     "Second yellow card and red card" "Red Cards"                      
# [7] "Fouls Committed"                 "Fouls Suffered\r\n"              "Fouls causing a penalty"
```

This will remove any non-ASCII characters. One of the columns has linebreaks at the end of it. To remove these, too, you can use

```
gsub('\r|\n', '', iconv(names(foulbycountry1), to='ASCII', sub=''))
```

Comment: str() shows everything is fine. But when I want to do something, it says unexpected symbol.



    > foulbycountry1$Matches Played
    Error: unexpected symbol in "foulbycountry1$Matches Played"

Comment: well there's a space in the name. Either surround the name with backticks, e.g., ```foulbycountry1$`Matches Played` ``` or call `names(foulbycountry1) <- make.names(names(foulbycountry1))` to replace the nonstandard characters.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep only the printable ASCII character in the column names, you can use

```
names(foulbycountry1) <- gsub("[^\x20-\x7F]","",names(foulbycountry1))
```

You can find a list of character codes [here](http://www.asciitable.com/). Here we specify the hex values with the `\x00` syntax.

Comment: Your solution also worked. I set the comment from @Mathew Plourde accepted since he was the first one :) Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is giving you an error? What code did you run?

Comment: It was my mistake. I didn't notice there exist spaces in the column names. It is working fine now.

Comment: If you wanted to remove spaces too, then you can use `gsub("[^\x21-\x7F]","",names(foulbycountry1))`