# Unicode in R displays using str() but not print() - how to use gsub()?

Tags: r, unicode, gsub

I'm importing text from pdf files using `pdf_text()`. The import picks up some unicode, but I can only see it using the `str()` function, but not `print()`.

For example, `print(x)` displays:

```
"CTO area performance..."
```

`str(x)` displays:

```
"<(u)+F0B7> CTO area performance..."
```

(note (u)+F0B7 is really U+F0B7 above)

How can I access the unicode `"\\<U+F0B7>"` using `gsub()`? Since it does not seem be in the text, I'm having trouble replacing it with a dash "-". I tried: `x <- gsub("<U\\+[0-9A-Z]{4}>", "-", x)` but it didn't work.

Comment: Try the solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38828620/how-to-remove-strange-characters-using-gsub-in-r/50398057#50398057

Comment: If you plan to remove any non-word chars from the beginning, you may also use `gsub("^\\W+", "", x)`. BTW, `U+FB07` is an unassigned character in Unicode.

Comment: If this works (it's an `iconv` solution) let us know so we can mark this a as a dup https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24807147/removing-unicode-symbols-from-column-names

Comment: To clarify, U+FB07 is a bullet from a bulleted list. I'm looking to replace it with a dash ("-") rather than eliminate it. It's also not just at the beginning, U+FB07 appears throughout the document.

Comment: Try a mere `sub("\\x{FB07}", "=>", x)`, you may even add `fixed=TRUE` argument (no need of regex here).

Comment: Thanks all. No luck yet. gsub("^\\W+", "", x) removed it from the beginning, but not subsequent instances. To clarify, I am not looking to remove it, but rather replace the unicode with a dash "-". Here's the output from the gsub - we can see the second U-F0B7 remains: "CTO area performance and Operational Stability remain strong\r\n     <U+F0B7> "

Comment: So, does `gsub("\\x{FB07}", "-", x)` solve the issue?

Comment: Yes! gsub("\\x{FB07}", "-", x) did the trick. Many thanks.