# how to clean weird symbols from csv file in r

Tags: r, csv, read.csv

I have a csv file which contains a lot of weird symbols. Example as below:

```
df = data.frame(comments = c('KoreaÂ¬Ãs Ministry of Food and Drug Safety is proposing an amendment seeking to amend the Standards and Specification','it is important to highlight:\nÂ¬Ã¯ Many maximum limits for drug',
                            'The European Parliament has published a decision, which aims to establish a special Committee to examine the EUÂ¬Ãs authorization procedure'))
write.csv(df, './example.csv', row.names = FALSE)
```

Does anyone know how I can clean up those weird symbols in R (or python). I have no clue why that happens and how to clean them up. Thanks a lot.

Comment: can you show yoour expected output

Comment: The "dupe" component of this is cleaning the data, it has nothing to do with writing to a CSV. (This problem has nothing to do with the CSV.)

Comment: @akrun    I'm not totally sure about the expected output. This is an example of the csv file I got. It contains those symbols. I suspect something to do with the encoding. But could not figure that out....

Comment: @r2evans I reopened the question because it was not clear about the expected output

Comment: @zesla If [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24807147/removing-unicode-symbols-from-column-names) solves the problem, then it can be dupe tagged

Answer (score 1):

Asauming that "weird" is everything that is not a "normal" letter, a number or a point or a comma:

```
gsub("[^A-z0-9\\. ,]", "", df$comment)
[1] "Koreas Ministry of Food and Drug Safety is proposing an amendment seeking to amend the Standards and Specification"                     
[2] "it is important to highlight Many maximum limits for drug"                                                                               
[3] "The European Parliament has published a decision, which aims to establish a special Committee to examine the EUs authorization procedure"
```

From here on you can add more symbols that are allowed.